# Dynamically generated label

Tags: labels

I would like to generate a label using a command that uses conditions:

```
\newcommand{\paperPrefix}[1][]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{\ifthenelse{\equal{\activePaper}{}}{}{\activePaper\_}}{#1\_}}
```

Basically it should return `#1_` if called with the optional parameter, `\activePaper_` if the macro activePaper is define (`\def\activePaper{...}`) and nothing (`''`)  otherwise.

However when I use it:

```
\label{\paperPrefix[MyPrefix]{}image}
```

Instead of defining a label in the form

```
\label{MyPrefix_image}
```

It complains that:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.<to be read again>\let ...eco]{}}{{1}{1}{Introduction}{chapter.1}{}}
```

So I was wondering, how to solve this.

Comment: The argument of `\label` must be expandable. LaTeX macros with optional arguments are not expandable, `\ifthenelse` is not expandable. Also `\_` is problematic. Therefore the interface has to be changed. For example, a macro performs the unexpandable stuff and defines a simple macro, which can be used later in `\label`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the fact that `\ifthenelse` does not work by expansion

```
\label{\paperPrefix[MyPrefix]{}image}
```

only has one argument (in `[]` ) so the `{}` before image is untouched and would form part of the label.

I think you want

```
\newcommand{\paperPrefix}[1]{\ifx\activePaper\defaultPaper\else#1_\fi}
```

together with

```
\newcommand\defaultPaper{}%or anything really
\newcommand\activePaper{}%same as above
```

then `\paperPrefix{mypaper}` (with `{} not []`) will expand to nothing by default or to `mypaper_` if `\activepaper` has been redefined.

Comment: Thanks, it works fabulously. To make it semantically match my original command I modified it to this: `\renewcommand{\paperPrefix}[1]{\ifx&#1&\ifx\activePaper\empty\else\activePaper_\fi\else#1_\fi}` . I just wonder how to make it so that it can be both used in `\label{}` and directly to output text (for debugging). I had to modify it as `\newcommand{\paperPrefix}[1]{\def\tst{#1}\ifx&#1&{\ifx\activePaper\empty\detokenize{}\else\activePaper\detokenize{_}\fi}\else\detokenize{#1_}\fi}` to be able to see the output (because otherwise `_` caused the `missing $` issue.