# Control space not expanding in label command

Tags: labels, expansion

Somehow a control space `\` used in `\label` doesn't expand. `\foo` gives the following newlabel in the aux file: *Anonymous\ 1*. Mind the backslash. The log gives: "! Missing `\endcsname` inserted." `\baz` does give the desired result in the aux file: *Anonymous 2*.

I guess this is related to the question [Dynamically generated label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310670/dynamically-generated-label) in which mr Oberdiek replies: "Also `\_` is problematic. Therefore the interface has to be changed." (Does this mean it cannot be done?)

Why doesn't the control space expand in `\label`? I *think* I can also phrase this question differently: why doesn't a control space expand when used (in combination with some other characters) between `\csname` `\endcsname`? I can't figure it out.

Is there any way to get `\foo` i.e. `\name\` working as well? Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\name}{Anonymous}
\newcommand{\foo}{\label{person:\name\ 1}\name}
\newcommand{\baz}{\label{person:\name{} 2}\name}
\begin{document}
    \foo
    \baz
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not stick to your definition of `\baz`, rather than a control space in `\foo`?

Comment: The `\<space>` primitive is not expandable. So it doesn't expand in a label and it's illegal inside the `\csname` construct that associates a ref to a label. What's the purpose of having `\<space>` in a label anyway?

Comment: The code is a minimal example. I'd like to generelize the input of names and using the input as a label. By using shorthands for certain names, I try to make it a bit easier. But if it cannot be done this way, I'll just find some other one. :)

Answer (score 4):

Let's tackle the problem more generally.

If you say

```
\section{Title}\label{foo}
```

and the section happens to be number 2.4, falling on page 35, LaTeX will write

```
\newlabel{foo}{{2.4}{35}}
```

When the `.aux` file is read in at the next run, the `\newlabel` command will essentially perform

```
\expandafter\gdef\csname r@foo\endcsname{{2.4}{35}}
```

so that `\ref{foo}` and `\pageref` will be able to extract the relevant information.

The definition of `\label` is

```
% latex.ltx, line 4195:
\def\label#1{\@bsphack
  \protected@write\@auxout{}%
         {\string\newlabel{#1}{{\@currentlabel}{\thepage}}}%
  \@esphack}
```

which has the consequence that the argument to `\label` is subject to full expansion.

Now let's consider `\label{foo\ 1}`. What gets written would be

```
\newlabel{foo\ 1}{{2.4}{35}}
```

because the primitive `\<space>` is not expandable, so a write operation leaves it unchanged.

Now when the `.aux` file is read in, LaTeX tries to do

```
\expandafter\gdef\csname r@foo\ 1\endcsname{{2.4}{35}}
```

and here the error pops up: the token `\<space>` is *illegal* inside `\csname`. Only character tokens and macros expanding to character tokens are legal.

Changing the code for the `\label`-`\ref` mechanism in order to allow `\<space>` is out of the question. Besides, what's the purpose of having `\<space>` in a `\label`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\name}{Anonymous}
\newcommand{\foo}{\label{person:\name\space1}\name}% or \name\space 1, same result
\begin{document}
\section{Test}

\foo

See also \ref{person:Anonymous 1} which is same as \ref{person:\name\space1}.

\end{document}
```

i.e. you want a space in your label and as far as I understand your problem is that it disappeared when using `\name<space>`. The `\name{}` approach works too, but then `{}` must be used when using the label in a `\ref` or similar macros.

Output:

[image]